# Duplicate Entries getting created for a single transient object

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In my case, I have two parent transient objects and one transient child object. I set the child object in the two parent transient objects and then save the parent objects. The relation from parent to child has Cascade Type ALL. Now two entries of the child object are getting created and mapped with parent object but I want only one entry of the child to get created and get mapped with 2 parent objects.
Is it possible in hibernate and if yes, then how?

I already ensured that same child object (same reference) is being set in both the parent objects but still no luck.

Comment: 1) How is equals implemented? 2) How is the primary key genreate?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli equals is not overridden and the primary key is autogenerated by generation type identity.

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicates you should implement the equals with a unique key (not the generated id)